# ActiveRecord transaction is not rolling back whole transaction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, transactions

I've got a ticket model and users can buy tickets in series starting from a given serial number. The users choose the number of tickets they want to buy and the controller generates that number of tickets and stores in the database. However if one ticket fails to save, the transaction should roll back but in this case it is not.

tickets_controller.rb

```
...
def create
  number = params[:ticket_qty].to_i
  @tickets = Array.new
  number.times do |n|
    t = Ticket.new(ticket_params)
    t.serial_number = t.serial_number.to_i + n 
    @tickets.push(t)
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do 
      @tickets.each do |t| 
        if t.save
          format.html { redirect_to tickets_path, notice: "#{number} #{"ticket".pluralize(number)} successfully created." }
          format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: tickets_path }
        else
          format.html { render :new, notice: "Some tickets have errors, check the serial number range" }
          format.json { render json: @ticket.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
...
```

Also the redirection is correct but no notice is showing up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to have your transaction rolled back in case of error, replace `t.save` with `t.save!`

This would result in:

```
respond_to do |format|
  begin 
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do 
      @tickets.each &:save!
      format.html { redirect_to tickets_path, notice: "#{number} #{"ticket".pluralize(number)} successfully created." }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: tickets_path }
    end
  rescue ActiveRecord::ActiveRecordError => e
    format.html { render :new, notice: "Some tickets have errors, check the serial number range" }
    format.json { render json: e.message, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

Comment: Awesome, this works for the transaction but sadly the error notice is not coming out, any ideas? The notice shows for success though

Comment: `render json: @ticket.errors` gave you an array, which is no more the case with my edit, could be the reason

Comment: Had to use flash[:notice] on the html format for the error message to pop up

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to save all records and trigger a rollback manually depending on the result:

```
Ticket.transaction do 
  @save_results = @tickets.map(&:save)
  raise ActiveRecord::Rollback unless @save_results.all?
end

respond_to do |format|
  if @save_results.all?
    format.html # ...
    format.json # ...
  else
    format.html # ...
    format.json # ...
  end
end
```

You can use `@save_results` to show the number of failed records:

```
"#{@save_results.count(false)} tickets have errors, ..."
```

Comment: Nice, this allows me to also list the ticket serials with errors!

Comment: did not know about `all?`, which in this case "will return true only if none of the collection members are false or nil." pretty neat.